# Adding cookies to my game

Tags: javascript, cookies

So, I'm currently creating a cookie clicker like game. And I need to add cookies to my JavaScript code so I won't lose all of my cookies when refreshing the page.
JavaScript code down below.

```
var cookies = 0;

function cookieClick(number){
cookies = cookies + number;
document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};

var cursors = 0;

function buyCursor(){
var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(cookies >= cursorCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        cursors = cursors + 1;                                   //increases number of     cursors
        cookies = cookies - cursorCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    };
var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}; 

var grandmas = 0;

function buyGrandma(){
var grandmaCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,grandmas));     //works out the cost of this grandma
if(cookies >= grandmaCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the grandma
    grandmas = grandmas + 1;                                   //increases number of grandmas
    cookies = cookies - grandmaCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
    document.getElementById('grandmas').innerHTML = grandmas;  //updates the number of grandmas for the user
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
};
var nextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,grandmas));       //works out the cost of the next grandma
document.getElementById('grandmaCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the grandma cost for the user
};

window.setInterval(function(){

    cookieClick(cursors);

}, 1000);
window.setInterval(function(){

    cookieClick(grandmas);

}, 400);
```

HTML code down below.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <img src="http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/7/70/Cookie.png?version=3afa70a9c4eea17707300251844f3c1c" onclick="cookieClick(1)" />
    <br />
    Cookies: <span id="cookies">0</span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
    <br />
    Cursors: <span id="cursors">0</span><img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2566/horizon/16/cursor.png" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="buyGrandma()" title="Gives 4 cookies every second">Buy Grandma</button>Cost: <span id="grandmaCost">100</span>
    <br />
    Grandmas: <span id="grandmas">0</span><img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130710043044/pokemontowerdefensetwo/images/1/18/Grandmum_icon.png" style="width:16px; height:20px;" />
    <br />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `localStorage` instead.

```
window.localStorage.numberOfCookiesCollected = 123456;
```

Reload the page

```
alert(window.localStorage.numberOfCookiesCollected); // 123456
```

Comment: Could you maybe add it to the code? I'm not the best JavaScript coder. I haven't worked with localStorage nor cookies yet.

Comment: Seriously? The code I gave you is literally all you need. Set a property on `window.localStorage` to save it, it will stay there even if you close the browser and come back a month later, you can access it like any other object.

Comment: `window.localStorage(cookies);` like that? I got NaN cookies after refreshing and clicking the cookie.